# Поделить строку на n-ое количество частей, с одинаковым количеством элементов, включая пробелы

Tags: python

Необходимо написать функцию pagination, которая разделит строку на n количество частей с равным количеством символов в каждой части, включая все элементы в т.ч. пробелы. И вернет результат в виде вложенных списков.

**Ожидаемый результат:**

```
string = 'I love to play Basketball, Football and Tennis'
print(pagination(string, 6)
[['I love to'], [' play Bas'], ['ketball, '], ['Football '], ['and Tenni'], ['s']]
```

Мой код:

```
def pagination(str, n):
    newString = str.split(maxsplit=n)
    resList = []
    for i in newString:
        resList.append([i])
    return resList
```

Результат:

```
string = 'I love to play Basketball, Football and Tennis'
print(pagination(string, 5))

[['I'], ['love'], ['to'], ['play'], ['Basketball,'], ['Football and Tennis']]
```

Comment: Ну а зачем вам сплит, если по пробелам делить не нужно? Срезами воспользуйтесь, да и всё

Comment: split() разделяет по пробелам. Как это связано в вашей задачей?

Comment: Не надо называть переменные `str`, т.е. зарезервированными словами в Python. Много шишек на этом можно набить…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```python
pagination = lambda s, n : [[s[i:i+n]] for i in (range(0,len(s),n))]

string = 'I love to play Basketball, Football and Tennis'
print(pagination(string, 9))
```

###### Вывод:

```console
[['I love to'], [' play Bas'], ['ketball, '], ['Football '], ['and Tenni'], ['s']]
```