# Как разделить строку по два символа в кортеж?

Tags: python

*Если кратко*, дана строка `some text`. Результат нужен типа такой: `[('so','me'), (' е', 'ex'), ('t')]`.

Ранее подсмотрел в интернете и по невнимательности сделал так:

```
data= 'some text'
step = 2
splitted_data = [tuple(data[i:i+step]) for i in range(0, len(data), step)]
```

Но результат здесь не тот: `[('s', 'o'), ('m', 'e'), (' ', 't'), ('e', 'x'), ('t',)]`. Думал со вложенным циклом туда же сделать,  но так я не умею

Comment: Вроде похоже на [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1474772/531666), только tuple вместо list внутри

Comment: а почему там в кортеже встречается один символ? должно быть ``[('so','me') (' t', 'ex'), ('t')]``

Comment: @Эникейщик да, логика примера непонятна

Comment: Покажите пример разбиения для `'hello world'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Немного дополнив [мой предыдущий ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1474772/531666) получим:

```python
data='some text'
pagination = lambda s, n : [ s[i:i+n] for i in (range(0,len(s),n)) ]
N=2
full_list = pagination(data, 2)
splitted_data = [tuple(full_list[n:n+N]) for n in range(0, len(full_list), N)]
print('splitted data:', splitted_data)
```

###### Вывод:

```
[('so', 'me'), (' t', 'ex'), ('t',)]
```

Как объединить элементы внутри списка [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4998460/8489602).

В одну строчку, конечно, это можно написать, но т.к. нам нужно знать размерность искомого списка, получится слишком муторно.

Comment: А зачем у вас во второй строчке пробелы в начале и конце списка? Это какое-нибудь неизвестное мне соглашение, касающееся лямбд?

Comment: @Глеб, лямбда тут не при чем, просто когда list comprehension вписан в какой-то ещё код, а внутри куча всего, квадратные скобки лучше вынести для читаемости и не лепить к другим элементам. Никаких соглашений по этому поводу нет, лично мне так удобнее.

Comment: @Глеб отвечал тогда с мобильного, сейчас с компьютера пересмотрел. Как видите, во втором случае со `splitted_data` прилепил. Но почему? Потому что внутри нет других квадратных скобок, в первом же варианте идёт slice, и, ИМХО, лучше отлепить, чтобы было видно, где начало и закрытие slice, иначе если прилепить хрючево получается. Но в моём подходе нет единства и целостности, что плохо. Хорошо бы узнать что об этом говорит PEP. На этапе разработки мне удобнее так, а перед коммитами в репу, я всё равно код прогоняю через black или другой линтер.

Comment: PEP 8 говорит дословно следующее: Avoid extraneous whitespace in the following situations:
Immediately inside parentheses, brackets or braces:
`# Correct:`
`spam(ham[1], {eggs: 2})`
`# Wrong:`
`spam( ham[ 1 ], { eggs: 2 } )`

Comment: Первый случай, по-моему, пробелы только уродуют. А во-втором случае — круглые скобки ничем не лучше квадратных, сразу не поймешь.

Comment: @Глеб ну вот на всус и цвет, да )

Answer (score 0):

```
data= 'some text'
step = 2
splitted_data = []

i=0
for n in range(int(len(data)/step)):
    splitted_data.append (data[i:i+2])
    i+=step
    
print (tuple(splitted_data))
```

Вывод будет:

```
('so', 'me', ' t', 'ex')
```

Если нужно группировать по два результата (по два символа), то можно так:

```
for n in range(int(len(data)/step/2)):
    splitted_data.append (tuple([data[i:i+2], data[i+2:i+4]]))
    i+=step+2
    
print (splitted_data)
```

Тогда вывод будет такой:

```
[('so', 'me'), (' t', 'ex')]
```

Если потеря последнего символа у которого нет пары является критичной, то можно дописать условие в конце:

```
if i!=len(data):
    splitted_data.append (tuple([data[i:]]))
```

Comment: Во втором примере **t** потерялась

Comment: да как и в первом, т.к. разбивается по два символа, а `t` получается лишним

Comment: Значит лишнее надо выводить в единственном экземпляре. Подсмотрите [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4998460/8489602)